# Creación de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

debo crear el javascript para que cuando elija el plan uno se deshabilite viaje en barco y paracaídas, cuando elija el plan 2 quede habilitado solo bebidas y cuando elija el plan 3 se me des habiliten las tres opciones.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <td data-name="Tiponegociacion_">
        <p style="margin: 0px">Tipo Negociacion<span class="required">*</span></p>
        <select name = "MisOpciones" id="TipoNegociacion" style="width: 300px;">
            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
            <option id ="123" value="1">Plan1</option>
            <option id ="456" value="2">Plan2</option>
            <option id ="789" value="3">Plan3</option>

        </select>
        <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border: 0px;">
        
    </td>
<div class="col-sm-2">
        <p style="margin: 0px">Bebidas Ilimitadas</p>
    <select id="bebIlm" style="width: 65px;">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p style="margin: 0px">Viaje en barco</p>
    <select id="bar" style="width: 65px;">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p style="margin: 0px">Paracaídas</p>
    <select id="par" style="width: 65px;">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <script src="Este es el javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo colocando clases a los `<select>` de esta forma puedes identificar cuales debes activar o desactivar, he modificado tu código y creado el `javascript` necesario para que tengas una idea de como hacerlo:

```js
var elm = document.getElementById("TipoNegociacion");
elm.addEventListener("change", function() {
 var plan = this[this.selectedIndex].innerText,
  sel = document.querySelectorAll(".disabled");
 sel.forEach(function(e){
  e.disabled = e.classList.contains(plan) ? true : false;
 })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <td data-name="Tiponegociacion_">
        <p style="margin: 0px">Tipo Negociacion<span class="required">*</span></p>
        <select name = "MisOpciones" id="TipoNegociacion" style="width: 300px;">
            <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
            <option id ="123" value="1">Plan1</option>
            <option id ="456" value="2">Plan2</option>
            <option id ="789" value="3">Plan3</option>

        </select>
        <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border: 0px;">
        
    </td>
<div class="col-sm-2">
        <p style="margin: 0px">Bebidas Ilimitadas</p>
    <select id="bebIlm" style="width: 65px;" class="disabled Plan3">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p style="margin: 0px">Viaje en barco</p>
    <select id="bar" style="width: 65px;" class="disabled Plan1 Plan2 Plan3">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p style="margin: 0px">Paracaídas</p>
    <select id="par" style="width: 65px;" class="disabled Plan1 Plan2 Plan3">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <script src="Este es el javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Por cierto des-habilitar Viaje en barco y Paracaídas, y habilitar solo bebidas, producen el mismo resultado.

Espero esto te sirva de ayuda. ;))....

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo de esta manera, quise hacerlo lo mas entendible posible para que comprendas el funcionamiento del script:

```js
// Capturamos el select por el id de cada uno 
var opciones = document.getElementById('TipoNegociacion');
var bebidas = document.getElementById('bebIlm');
var barco = document.getElementById('bar');
var paracaidas = document.getElementById('par');

// Agregamos un evento que se dispara cada vez que ocurre un cambio
opciones.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
 
  //Colocamos todos los input como disabled cada vez que ocurre un cambio
  bebidas.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  barco.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  paracaidas.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  // capturamos el valor de opciones y activamos la opcion que necesitamos
  if(opciones.value == 1){
  //removeAttribute nos ayuda a remover el atributo del elemento
    paracaidas.removeAttribute("disabled");
    barco.removeAttribute("disabled");;
  }else if(opciones.value == 2){
    bebidas.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }else if(opciones.value == 3){
    paracaidas.removeAttribute("disabled");
    bebidas.removeAttribute("disabled");
    barco.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<td data-name="Tiponegociacion_">
        <p style="margin: 0px">Tipo Negociacion<span class="required">*</span></p>
        <select name = "MisOpciones" id="TipoNegociacion" style="width: 300px;">
            <option>Seleccione...</option>
            <option id ="123" value="1">Plan1</option>
            <option id ="456" value="2">Plan2</option>
            <option id ="789" value="3">Plan3</option>

        </select>
        <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border: 0px;">
        
    </td>
<div class="col-sm-2">
        <p style="margin: 0px">Bebidas Ilimitadas</p>
    <select id="bebIlm" style="width: 65px;" disabled>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p style="margin: 0px">Viaje en barco</p>
    <select id="bar" style="width: 65px;" disabled>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p style="margin: 0px">Paracaídas</p>
    <select id="par" style="width: 65px;" disabled>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Si</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda!